# System of linear equations with parameter - strange result, does this make sense

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have a system of linear equations $Ax = b$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$, and $x,b = \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 1}$.

$A$ has some parameter $\alpha$ in its entries.

I was asked to find for which values of $\alpha$ does this system have a unique solution, no solutions and infinite many solutions.

I found two different problematic values for $\alpha$, but my problem is that it seems like in both these values, I have infinite solutions.

There seems to be no case in which we have no solution, 2 different cases where we get infinite many solutions, and the rest ofcourse is unique.

Does this make sense? this is the first question I encountered where there is no value for no solutions and 2 different values for infinite solutions. so far its been one value of alpha for each, but I checked myself 5 times and I've yet to find a mistake.

I don't want to trouble you with the details of the problem, just the final question - does this situation make sense or did I make a mistake for sure?

Comment: Give us the system, it will be simpler to give you an adapted answer.

Comment: Unless you provide $A,b$ this is a question about the psychology of setting tests rather than about maths!

Comment: I'd rather not as I was asked not to share the details of the problem. This is not a psychology question. "Can a linear system of equations with one parameter have two different values of the parameter for which the system has infinite solutions and no values for which there is no solution" is strictly a mathematical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example concerning your question ""Can a linear system of equations with one parameter have two different values of the parameter for which the system has infinite solutions". Consider the three linear equations
$$
x=0, y=0, \alpha(\alpha-1)z=0.
$$
For $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=0$ there are infinitely many solutions $(0,0,z)\in K^3$, provided the field $K$ is infinite. Otherwise there is only the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks! that helped! Guess I should be more confident in my abilities.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, confidence is good, but control is better (or something like this).

Answer (score 0):

Lets us have a look at this simple system:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\
0         & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It will have either unique solutions ($\alpha \ne 0$) or infinite many solutions. But no case of no solution.
So such systems exist.